# Sudoku solver backtracking

Tags: java, backtracking, sudoku

I'm browsing through some sudoku solvers and I'm looking for one that utilizes backtracking, now I've found this code but I'm not really sure whether it uses backtracking or some other algorithm?

Help is appreciated.

```
abstract class SudoKiller {
private SudokuBoard sb;    // Puzzle to solve;

public SudoKiller(SudokuBoard sb) {
    this.sb = sb;
}


private boolean check(int num, int row, int col) {
    int r = (row / sb.box_size) * sb.box_size;
    int c = (col / sb.box_size) * sb.box_size;

    for (int i = 0; i < sb.size; i++) {
        if (sb.getCell(row, i) == num ||
            sb.getCell(i, col) == num ||
            sb.getCell(r + (i % sb.box_size), c + (i / sb.box_size)) == num) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


public boolean guess(int row, int col) {
    int nextCol = (col + 1) % sb.size;
    int nextRow = (nextCol == 0) ? row + 1 : row;

    try {
        if (sb.getCell(row, col) != sb.EMPTY)
            return guess(nextRow, nextCol);
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return true;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= sb.size; i++) {
        if (check(i, row, col)) {
            sb.setCell(i, row, col);
            if (guess(nextRow, nextCol)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    sb.setCell(sb.EMPTY, row, col);
    return false;
}
}
```

And if this is not backtracking, is there an easy way to "convert" to it?

The whole project can be found on [the authors site](http://www.kernel-panic.it/software/sudokiller/sudokiller.java.html).

Comment: Have you looked at the definition of backtracking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it does backtracking via recursion.

Here we step forward:

```
sb.setCell(i, row, col);
```

and here we step backward:

```
sb.setCell(sb.EMPTY, row, col);
```

Comment: How can you see that it is a backtracking algorithm?
And is there a way to add a delay so I can see the backtracking in real-time (as it happens).

Comment: @BobSmith Added more details to the answer.